# Understand Date string

Tags: javascript, date

All:

When I build a Date object from a string like:

```
var dt = new Date("2016-05-31 07:35:22+02:00");
```

I wonder what that string means? I thought it means its geographical local time is 7:35:22 and GMT is 9:35:22, but when I use dt.toUTCString(), I get

> "Tue, 31 May 2016 05:35:22 GMT"

, this is so confused. I wonder which part is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The time you've posted is 2 hours ahead of UTC (`+2:00`), hence when you get it as UTC, it is two hours behind the given value. 05:35+00 = 07:35+2:00. So, there's nothing wrong here at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The +2:00 part tells you that this local time is in a timezone/DST that is currently 2 hours ahead of UTC. Hence, you would need to subtract two hours from this time to attain UTC time. So, 07:35+2:00 = 05:35+0:00. Nothing wrong with the values at all.

Further reading:

http://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones.html

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

http://joshowens.me/dealing-with-timezones-in-javascript/

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me how many time string format can Date() accept?

Comment: Several, but it's best to instantiate a JavaScript Date object using new Date(year, month, day) given the issues with cross-browser/region compatibility regarding format strings. Or use Moment.js.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the current local time is 7:35:22 and the location is 2 hours ahead of GMT.

That's why utc is showing as two hours earlier than the time

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me how many time string format can Date() accept?

Comment: You can add any number in the format you wrote instead of the +02:00. You can read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 1):

The +02:00 at the end means the time you provided is 2 hours **ahead of** UTC.

So if UTC is 05:30, UTC+1 is 06:30, UTC+2 is 07:30 etc

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me how many time string format can Date() accept?